# Angular ag-grid data loading from api

Tags: angular, api, lazy-loading, ag-grid

I am now working on a project to get data from api and display in angular ag-grid. The problem is that getting data from api took a long time. It took up to 5-15 seconds to get reply while testing with postman. I thought about using lazy loading to separately request data per page.

However, I might have to re-call api again and again to show data in each page and will have problems for sorting and filtering. I tried searching tutorial examples but all of them are tested with rowData already inside the project. For me, I have to request from api. What should I do about it? Is it problem from api side?

For now, I am thinking that I will divide the data request from api into two phase. At first, I will request only about 20 rows of data from api and show it in ag-grid. As soon as the data loaded on screen, behind background, a new api call will be made to call all data and then update ag-grid. Is there any way to auto-update ag-grid as soon as data in rowData change? Is there any methods for recommendation?

P.S. We also create api so can make new api.

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/

Comment: you could use [Infinite Row Model](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#example-simple) of [tag:ag-grid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [Infinite Row Model](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#example-simple) feature of ag-grid. Just check the documentation to get the clear idea on how to configure this. I will walk you through some basic steps in order to make you understand how to implement this.

As a first step you need to configure the following properties in the gridOptions along with your other options.

```
{
  rowModelType: 'infinite',
  cacheBlockSize: 20,
  datasource: myDataSource
}
```

Here the cacheBlockSize is set to 20 since you are having the request page row count as 20 from API. You can configure this according to your requirement.

Since you are using infinite row model, you can't set the grid data directly instead you need to use a data source.

```
const myDataSource: IDatasource = {
    rowCount: null,
    getRows: (params: IGetRowsParams) => {
        yourApiRequestService.subscribe((data) => {
            let lastRow = -1;
            if (data.length <= params.endRow) {
                lastRow = data.length;
            }

            params.successCallback(data, lastRow);
        });
    }
};
```

I already set this myDataSource to the datasource property in the gridOptions provided.

Having these configured will makes the grid to automatically fetch the data when its want to display. Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: thanks you. I already tried with infinite scrolling. But the problem is that the loading time is in api calling. According to my testing, the moment the code request data from api link using http.get<any>() method, the delay occurs. Infinite scrolling is only available only after loading the link. So, currently I am using two api links. Upon page loading, I called data from separate api which call less data thus faster loading time and show it in grid. As soon as I get data from first api, I call from the main api and then update the grid. I will try your method too.. Thanks.